# Quartz 2.0 scheduler exceptions

Tags: quartz-scheduler

we are using quartz 2.0 framework. I just downloaded quartz packages and placed it in the build path of my project. If i execute the same schedular i used for quartz 1.6, it is throwing the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<init>(StdSchedulerFactory.java:274)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1480)
    at QuartzTest.main(QuartzTest.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:346)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)
    ... 3 more
```

My code as of now, if just starting and stopping schedular. I will appreciate, if any body could help me out in this.

Also in 2.x version, the way we would create an object for jobdetail seems to be a bit different. If i create an object in this manner:

```
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("jobDetail-s1", "jobDetailGroup-s1", SimpleQuartzJob.class);
```

IDE says ..cannot instantiate the type JobDetail.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that **Quartz 2.0 is not supported by Spring 3** branch until the release of Spring 3.1
See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/changelog.txt) (Spring release notes).

This drove me nuts too as their examples and our old code did not work anymore. I assumed that we'd broken something, however it was Spring/Quartz that broke it. I switched back to Quartz 1.5.2 and Spring 3.0.5 and everything works well.

Another example of the vagaries of Spring dogma.

Answer (score 0):

The [Quartz 2.x Migration Guide](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide) has everything you need